# Increment filename-number by the amount of files in directory .Net

Tags: vb.net, auto-increment, winscp-net

My program finds and lists all files located on a remote folder.
The same program is able to save new files created into the same folder.
I can decide the filename, but I need the program to give some sort of "ID" to each of them.
I would like the program to be able to Count the number of files in the folder at all times, and name the file being saved as the next number in line.

See, I have 10 files in the folder. And I go in to create a new one using the New_Case Event. I write in a bunch of information and in the end hit Save_Case event.
I want the program to name the file "Somename11"

And then, since its now 11 files in the folder I do the same and create a New Case - Bunch of information - and Save, and the next file will be called "Someothername12".

I have yet to find any examples that works, but I found many where the number increases if the filename already exists in the folder.
I need the Number to increase regardless.

I have tried using a Counter that increments each time, but since this program will be used by multiple users at the same time, I need to avoid two users incrementing the same digit.

So by incrementing it by the number of files in the folder would work much better I believe.

If it helps to nail this down, I am unable to use

My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles

as it's remote, and that only wanna search my PC.

I am using WinSCP .NET to have an SFTP to the Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most efficient thing in the world, but it's a simple way to accomplish your stated goal:

```
Public Function SaveWithUniqueFileName(desiredFilePath As String, contents() As Byte) As String
    Dim uniqueFilePath As String = Nothing
    Dim suceeded As Boolean = False
    For i As Integer = 1 To Integer.MaxValue
        If i = 1 Then
            uniqueFilePath = desiredFilePath
        Else
            Dim uniqueFileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(desiredFilePath) & i.ToString() & Path.GetExtension(desiredFilePath)
            uniqueFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(desiredFilePath), uniqueFileName)
        End If
        If Not File.Exists(uniqueFilePath) Then
            Try
                Using stream As New FileStream(uniqueFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
                    stream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length)
                End Using
                suceeded = True
                Exit For
            Catch ex As IOException
            End Try
        End If
    Next
    If Not suceeded Then
        uniqueFilePath = Nothing
    End If
    Return uniqueFilePath
End Function
```

That method will save to the desired file name if it doesn't already exist, or append a unique number to the file name if one does already exist.  For instance, if you you call it like this:

```
 Dim data() As Byte = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111}
 Dim savedToPath As String = SaveWithUniqueFileName("C:\Test.txt", data)
 If savedToPath IsNot Nothing Then
     Console.WriteLine("Successfully saved to " & savedToPath)
 Else
     Console.WriteLine("Failed to save")
 End If
```

There are many improvements to be made.  It ought to have some cap on how high it counts and it should handle the exception better than just eating it and returning null (ideally the consuming code would know why it failed).  Also, it loops through all the same-named files starting at 1, so the more files there are with the same name, the slower it would go.  If performance is an issue, you could have some way to sync all the clients so that they don't all try to save at the same time.  That could be as simple as locking a single flag file in the same folder, or it could be as involved as a client/server arrangement where all clients send requests to a single server which handles the saving in an orderly serial fashion.  Either way, this simple example is a good place to start.

Comment: The OP wrote: "*I found many (examples) where the number increases if the filename already exists in the folder. I need the Number to increase regardless.*

Comment: Yes, I have already made the Increase number if Filename-exist way work. Used some Counters and stuff. But I need to increase the number even if the new filename is completely different. "Thisfilename1" "Thatfilename2" ect. Know anyway of doing that yourself, Martin?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl true, but he also explained the reason why.  He said "*I need to avoid two users incrementing the same digit.*"  My example shows a way of accomplishing that without the need to skip numbers. Using the total count of files as the counter would be trivial, but it wouldn't solve the stated problem. If two users both tried to same the same file name at the same time, and the folder currently had 50 files of various names in it, so it just skipped ahead to "somefile50", then both users would end up picking the same file name and it would result in the same conflict.

Comment: If that's really what you want, though, @PiperMp3, I you could do it with a similar loop that starts at the total count and continues to increase from that number until it finds one that doesn't fail.

Comment: In essence, this is a better explanation.. I need the program to give 1 number, only ONCE. Say if it gives "Thisfilename" the number 1 making it "Thisfilename1", No new files EVER will get the number "1" ? Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, but so would your proposed method, potentially. To avoid that, you'd need to store the next number to a common file. The simplest and most efficient way to avoid repeated names is to use GUIDs as the file names.

Comment: Oh right! GUIDs! How did I forget those!
Well, Steven, much appreciated, Thank you!